# turing machine decidability language

Tags: computability, automata, formal-languages, turing-machines

I must show that this language is decidable but I think it's not

{D, Ρ} | D is a DFA and P is a ΡDA which L(D) ∩ L(Ρ) = ∅ }
Here what I think

I give a reduction from E(TM). I suppose that this language is decidable.
Let T be a Turing machine that decides it. Then we can construct a Turing machine $T'$ deciding E(TM), that behaves as follows on input $\langle D,P\rangle$.

(a) Simulate T on input $\langle D,D'\rangle$, where $D'$ is a Turing machine recognizing the empty language.

(b) Accept if and only if T accepts.

Suppose that D accepts the empty language. Then T accepts $\langle D, 
D'\rangle$, and so $T'$ accepts.

But suppose that D accepts some string. Then T rejects $\langle D, D'\rangle$, and so
$T'$ rejects. Thus, $T'$ decides (ETM).

Can anyone help?

Comment: What is the purpose of $D'$? $T$ will never accept a Turing machine because it only accepts pairs of DFA and PDA, hence it cannot decide E(TM), at least not without modification.

Comment: @HenningMakholm is this i wrote completely wrong?

Comment: @theorcp: Completely, I'm afraid. The language is in fact decidable ...

Answer (score 2):

There are two major problems that prevent your argument from working.

First, you're completely missing that *a Turing machine is not the same as a DFA*. DFAs are much weaker than Turing machine, but in your construction you seem to be assuming that you can feed an arbitrary Turing machine into $T$, which is only assumed to work when its input is a DFA.

Second, even if we ignore the differences between machine types, if $D'$ accepts the empty language -- by which I assume you mean $L(D')=\varnothing$, then $L(D)\cap L(D')=\varnothing$ no matter what $D$ is, so your assumption that $T$ should reject $\langle D,D'\rangle$ if $D$ accepts anything is false. Here I think you have confused $\cap$ for $\cup$ in the problem statement.

---

The language you consider is actually decidable. A sketch of a procedure to decide this might be

1. Given a DFA $D$ and a new PDA $P$ we can construct a PDA $P'$ that accepts $L(D)\cap L(P)$ -- its states will be pairs of a $D$-state and a $P$-state.
2. Given a PDA you can construct a context-free grammar for the language it accepts.
3. Given a context-free grammar you can decide whether the language it generates is empty or not.

I will let you fill in the details -- how much work you need to do here depends on which prerequisites you already have available.

Comment: I might not have all the prerequisites that's why I am posting here

Comment: What details to fill?  you mean that I should prove all the procedure steps?

Comment: @theorcp: Yes, each of the steps needs to be explained, to the extent it is not already covered by your textbook or earlier exercises.

Comment: Can you help me a bit more? Because I can't prove them, it's a bit hard for me

Comment: @theorcp: I'm afraid that would start to veer into "doing your homework for you" territory.